# OnClickListener is not firing

Tags: android, google-maps, onclicklistener, buttonclick

i'm trying to define onClickListener to a button but it is just not working...

Here's the listener:

```
    Button buttonVolta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVolta);

    buttonVolta.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isTestMarker()){
                Location devolveCoord = getCoordenadas();
                Intent intent = new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("latitude", Double.toString(devolveCoord.getLatitude()));
                intent.putExtra("longitude", Double.toString(devolveCoord.getLatitude()));
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                TelaMapa.this.finishActivity(1);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(TelaMapa.this, "Marque um ponto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
```

it is inside a method that creates a map, the button is just below the map...

```
     @Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    configureMap(); 
}


/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void configureMap() {

...

}
```

here's the method calling and definition...

Comment: did you try adding log in the code?

Comment: tried, the listener is not fired... never... and also there is no errors in logcat...

Comment: I see that you have used setResult() in your onClick, are you click on right button check for buttonVolta in your manifest, if it doesn't work try clean the project and re build. Sometimes it's an issue with old R.java file.

Comment: Is the setting of the listener code in your onCreate()?

Comment: i didn't checked nothing in my manifest, and i don't know how to do it... if you can explain for me, i'll be happy... and you are right, toast is not showing for some reason, maybe the context, but the listener is firing... but it's not finishing the activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need to finish the current activity you should call just `finish()` instead of
`TelaMapa.this.finishActivity(1);`. `finishActivity` for finishing a child activity started by your current activity check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity(int)